# Why a custom method causes the default policy methods to disable?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.5. All we know the `resource` method of Gate facade contains CRUD methods by default. By the way, I add a custom method into policy class using resource method as a third argument like this:

**Registering Policy:**

```
Gate::resource('users', 'App\Policies\UserPolicy', ['edit' => 'edit']);
```

**Policy Class:**

```
use HandlesAuthorization;

public function before(Admin $admin)
{
    return $admin->isSuperAdmin();
}

/*public function view(Admin $admin)
{
    return true;
}*/

public function edit()
{
    return true;
}
```

But, this causes the default CRUD methods like `view` returns false. I use this abilities for certain routes using middleware helper.

```
Route::get('/view', 'UsersController@view')->middleware('admin-authorization:users.view');
Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit')->middleware('admin-authorization:users.edit');
```

So, `admin-authorization` is like this:

```
Auth::shouldUse('web_admin');
if (Gate::denies($ability)) {
    return abort(403);
}
return $next($request);
```

The default method and custom works fine on absence of each other. When I comment the `view` method, the `edit` method works fine and vice versa, and the `before` method is being called in two cases.

What should I do that the default and custom method work fine with each other? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When using `resources` it's not `view` but `show`

Comment: according to the Laravel Docs, it's `view` not `show`!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers `view` in your policy but `show` in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's weird, But i found the solution!!
we must pass an array into the `resource` as third argument that contains both custom and default methods like below:

```
Gate::resource('users', 'App\Policies\UserPolicy', ['view' => 'view'/*default*/, 'edit' => 'edit'/*custom*/]);
```

It's done well.